# Accessing raster dataset's attribute table?

Tags: raster, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3

I need to loop through the rows in the raster attribute table and add a date for each row.

Comment: which toolset to you have in mind?

Comment: CalculateField in Data Management Tools (.NET)

Comment: Is this a one-off (to "fix" data) or will you need to do it again in the future? Also, could you do it on the database side of things rather than programmatically via C#?

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to include the software name and version number, and preferred language (I figured this out from reading the answers and comments, but was about to post an answer using python which is not what you want).

Answer (score 2):

Because it has an attribute table, this is a categorical raster.  Why not, then, create a lookup table to match dates to categories and join the lookup table to the attribute table?  You probably already have a computer-readable version of this lookup table anyway, so this procedure might save considerable time and effort as well as reduce the error rate compared to a manual alternative.

Answer (score 1):

To loop using CalculateField as deskcheck1 mentions

ModelBuilder link for Iterate Row Selection 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Iterate_Row_Selection/004000000010000000/

*assumption using ArcGIS

Comment: Sorry.  We don't have ArcGIS 10 yet. I'm writing the code in C# using ArcGIS 9.3.1

Comment: I tried casting the raster dataset into a feature class, but it's not accepting it.